# Access Haxe / PHP variables from regular PHP file

Tags: php, haxe

I have built a webservice using Haxe, and targeted at PHP. The main way of outputting the data is via an image summarizing the results of the query.

However, I need to integrate some variables into a regular PHP file and make them accessible through some kind of communication between the php generated files and the user coded php files.

I have thought about declaring a function in the Haxe/PHP files that returns an associative array containing all the data I want, however I don't have enough knowledge of the Haxe environment to implement it and access it from a php file. I am not sure what should I include in the php side.

My questions are :

- Is my approach relevant ? If so, what would be the best way to implement it ?
- If not, what would you suggest ?

Any clue is welcome ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use the PHP target much anymore, but I think everything in Haxe is exposed to PHP, so you should be able to import the classes you require.

#### Importing the Haxe environment

Take a look at the generated `index.php`:

```
<?php

if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '<')) {
    exit('Your current PHP version is: ' . PHP_VERSION . '. Haxe/PHP generates code for version 5.1.0 or later');
}
;
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/php/php/Boot.class.php';

server_Server::main();

?>
```

The final line, "server_Server::main()", could be replaced by whatever function call or action you want to perform.  By default, it's executing the "main" method of whatever class you specified as "-main", in my case, "server.Server.main()"

#### Static functions calls:

Say I have a class with a public static function.  In Haxe, I would call:

```
  var testPassword = ufront.auth.model.User.generatePasswordHash("test", "test");
```

In PHP, the equivalent code is something like:

```
  $testPassword = ufront_auth_model_User::generatePasswordHash("test", "test");
```

#### Object creation:

If you had an object you wanted to create:

```
  var u = new ufront.auth.model.User();
```

In PHP that would be:

```
  $u = new ufront_auth_model_User();
```

#### General thoughts

Returning the types in Associative Arrays or similarly simple PHP data structures is probably a good idea, to make it as easy as possible to read without worrying about translating Haxe concepts / data structures to PHP ones.

If in doubt, look at the PHP code - it is fairly readable, and more so since Haxe 3.  (If you have `-debug` enabled, you will get a fair bit of extra code in your functions to help with stack traces etc, if you turn it off it may be simpler to read).

If you're trying to figure out what PHP syntax you would need to do something you know how to do in Haxe, write it in Haxe, and look at the generated PHP code.  Copy/Paste/Modify to your hearts content.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it has everything I wanted to know ! I have looked in the php files generated by haxe before, but it was so messy I was quickly discouraged to continue reading.

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences between basic data structures that you may need to bridge, which can be done using [`php.Lib`](http://haxe.org/api/php/Lib) - if necessary.

Beyond that difference between Haxe and PHP, you should consider that Haxe generated classes only have public members. That aside, they are perfectly usable in PHP.

You can also instantiate PHP classes from Haxe, if you make an according external declaration first.

Comment: I thought a hashmap would convert automatically to an associative array, but thank you for saving me time and headaches ! :)